# Import nodejs module with version number into typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, import

So I have a node module which seems to use a versioning system. Using nodejs I simply used

```
const Package = require('package-name').V1;
```

which worked without issues. Typescript however does not like the `.V1` so I use

```
import { Package } from 'package-name';
```

which complies fine but the typescript output to javascript is

```
const package_name_1 = require("package-name");
```

Which means that any function or properties of `package_name_1` are undefined since the module doesn't seem to load `V1.js` file (i assume that is how it works..)

So I tried

```
import * as Package from 'package-name';
```

But it outputs the same javascript as before..

The actual folder structure of the package I am using is

```
-node_modules
--package-name
---client
----v1
----v1.js
```

with the v1.js file looking like

```
var PackageV1 = {}

PackageV1.CONSTANTS = require('./v1/constants');
PackageV1.Request = require('./v1/request');
PackageV1.Session = require('./v1/session');
...

module.exports = PackageV1;
```

Of course things like

```
const Package = require('package-name.V1');
```

do not work

> Error: Cannot find module 'package-name.V1'

How can I require this `V1.js` file / directory using the typescript method?

Comment: What package specifically are you talking about? I Would expect `Package` in `import { Package } from 'package-name';` to have a property named `V1` and you could use that to access module members, but I don't know how the typings are written

Comment: Surely `import { V1 } from 'package-name';` or even `import { V1 as Package } from 'package-name';` depending on your own preference. BTW, nothing was ever stopping you from the similar `const { V1: Package } = require('package-name');` before, as the `import` construct uses a form of "destructuring" which is generally available in modern JavaScript environments.

Answer (score 0):

As was hinted at in the comments

```
import * as Package from 'package-name';
```

is fine but when using the package I had to use

```
Package.V1.Request()
```

rather than

```
Package.Request()
```

Comment: is it possible to use `package-name/v1`?